# Is the Unitary Group of a Hilbert Space a Lie group?

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, lie-groups, quantum-mechanics

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.  Then the set of unitary operators on $H$ forms a group, known as the unitary group or Hilbert group.  My question is, is this group a Lie group?  That is, is there a standard Lie group structure for this group?

I ask because in quantum mechanics, at least subgroups of this group seem to be treated as Lie groups.

EDIT: The second page of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/9904040.pdf) off-handedly mentions "the Frechet Lie group $U(H)$ consisting of all unitary operators on H, equipped with the strong operator topology".  What that means is that the Lie group structure on $U(H)$ with the strong operator topology is a Frechet manifold, i.e. a manifold which is locally isomorphic to a [Frechet space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) rather than a finite-dimensional Euclidean space.  But does anyone know the details of this Frechet manifold structure?

Comment: People search for a Lie group structure on $U(H)$ with the strong topology, see [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5891.pdf).

Comment: @DietrichBurde When you say people search for it, do you mean htey haven't found it?